# Binding a list of int from hidden field to property of a model in MVC c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Can we bind the following hidden field to a `List<int>` property of ViewModel in MVC ?

```
<input type="hidden" name="HiddenIntList" id="HiddenIntList" value="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]" />
```

Above hidden field fill with javascript.

ViewModel Property :

```
public List<int> HiddenIntList {get;set;}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `Html.HiddenFor()`?

Comment: @AmateurProgrammer: I meant `Html.HiddenFor()` actually

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. You can't bind complex types to hidden field. You can do this as following:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
    <input type="hidden" name="HiddenIntList" value="@Model[i]" />
}
```

and controller

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(List<int> HiddenIntList){...}
```

Check **[HERE](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)**